# How to access each element in the following JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

```
"email": "FamilyMembers: 54; Children: 4; Income: 8484; Literacy: UG; MaritalStatus: Married;
```

I am Trying this code

```
if (arr.email != undefined) {
         out += "Family Members:" + arr.email.FamilyMembers + "<br/>Children:" + arr.email.Children + "<br/>Income:" + arr.email.Income + "<br/>Literacy:" + arr.email.Literacy + "<br/>Marital Status:" + arr.email.MaritalStatus; 

    }
```

Comment: You've tried it! So?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON for starters. I'm struggling to see what structure your data is trying to model. I'm also struggling to see what you are trying to do in the code.

Comment: do you want to udpate your html whenever your json is updated?

Comment: @SamParmenter please don't struggle that much, just click the down vote and move on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON seems to be improperly formatted. If you do want to access the sub-elements of email as objects, your JSON should look like this:

```
 { "email" : { "FamilyMembers": 54,
            "Children": 4, 
            "Income": 8484, 
            "Literacy": "UG",
            "MaritalStatus": "Married"
          }
  }
```

Comment: You've demonstrated not a valid JSON string as well.

Comment: Okay, what's invalid?

Comment: copy it to any JSON validator and see!

Comment: @zerkms - I omitted the sourrounding `{}`, because this was what the original question did. But thanks for your constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be enough.

```
var p = {"email": "FamilyMembers: 54; Children: 4; Income: 8484; Literacy: UG; MaritalStatus: Married;"}

for (var key in p) {
  if (key == email) {
  var emailElt = p[key]
  for (var subKey in emailElt) {
      if (p.hasOwnProperty(subKey)) {
         alert(subKey + " -> " + emailElt[subKey]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parse it, for example :

```
var myString = arr.email;
var arrayOfKV = myString.split(";");
var obj = {};
while( elem = arrayOfKV.shift() ) {
  var kV = elem.split(":");
  obj[k] = V;
}


var properJSON = JSON.stringify({ email: obj });
```